# Cannot update Value of textbox in Gridview : Object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using edit template in my `gridview` to update some control values like `dropdowns`, `textboxes` etc.I am finding these control on update function as follows :

```
string dd1 = ((DropDownList)OwnerGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddl1")).SelectedItem.Text.Trim();

string actual = ((TextBox)OwnerGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtowneractual")).Text.Trim();
```

I have bound dropdowns from which i am selecting items before updating. I am also filling textboxes before updating. The textboxes are not binded.

When I am clicking on update, it is throwing "`Object reference not set to instance of an object`" error. I have debugged the code, `textbox` value is null while I am getting `dropdown` value.

What is the issue ?

Designer for textbox :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Actual" >

<EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtowneractual" Width="80px" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>                  

</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>               

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Please add the html for ddl also along with textbox.

Comment: in which gridview event you are getting it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your textbox is in Edit Item template due to which you are getting a null reference exception. try some thing like this

```
if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit )
 {
string actual = ((TextBox)OwnerGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtowneractual")).Text.Trim();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if id of your textbox is "txtowneractual".

And use the following code instead.

```
TextBox txtOwnerActual = (TextBox)OwnerGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtowneractual");

if(txtOwnerActual  != null)
{
       string actual = txtOwnerActual.Text.Trim();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked !!

TextBox txtOwnerActual = (TextBox)OwnerGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtowneractual"); instead of 
string actual = ((TextBox)OwnerGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtowneractual")).Text.Trim() ;